# ASP.NET Web API POST parameter is null When Properties of Class Defined as Auto-Implemented

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Anyone have any idea why the auto-implemented version of the class does not come through on a Post to the Web API?

```
namespace N_EWA
{
    public class testMe
    {
        public bool Pending { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However.... if I define the class and property as below.... it recognizes the incoming object and it works....

```
namespace N_EWA
{
    public class testMe
    {
        private bool pending { get; set; }

        public bool Pending
        {
            get { return pending; }
            set { pending = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense. It is very unlikely to be the cause of your issue

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The two are identical in function. Show more context of your code - I assure you there's a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to put this in comments but I think it warrents its own answer entry.

I thought about this overnight.... since [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) are created by the compiler itslef could it be that since I am running this as a [standard website and not a web application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that Web API is not able to work with the auto-implemented class/properties since the generated private fields used to manage the get/set of the property exist only in compiled code like you get when you have a web application?

Answer (score 0):

The offical answer is user error on my part....  :-)

For some unknown reason the complex object that I was trying to post had the booleans set to True and False (capital T and F)..... simply changing the values to true and false (all lowers) corrected the issue.